# How to get datas from related tables in Phalcon?

Tags: php, foreign-keys, relationship, has-many, phalcon

I have exactly the same structure like in the phalcon models documentation: 
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/_images/eer-1.png

In the models I implemented the following hasmany and belongsto lines:

Robots model:

```
class Robots extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public function initialize(){
        $this->hasMany("id", "RobotsParts", "robots_id");
    }
}
```

Parts model:

```
class Parts extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public function initialize(){
        $this->hasMany("id", "RobotsParts", "parts_id");
    }
}
```

RobotParts model:

```
class RobotsParts extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $id;
    public $robots_id;
    public $parts_id;
    public function initialize(){
        $this->belongsTo("robots_id", "Robots", "id");
        $this->belongsTo("parts_id", "Parts", "id");
    }
}
```

At this point I was hoping to get all the data by calling RobotParts::find(), but I can see only the id's.
For debuging I dumped, but find only the ids:(

```
$rp = RobotParts::find()->toArray();
var_dump($rp);
```

I would like to get something like this as result:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => int '1' (length=1)
      'robots_id' => int '4' (length=1)
          'name'  => string 'r2d2' (length=4)
          'type'  => string 'droid' (length=5)
          'year'  => int '2184' (length=4)
      'parts_id' => int '4' (length=1)
          'name'  => string 'wheel' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var_dump() does not contains the related tables, needed to reference to it from view like:

```
robots.RobotParts.name
```